# Can't Uncheck Windows 8 Target in Xamarin Project

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I have a Xamarin Cross Platform App in VS2017. I'm trying to add WCF service references and it seems I need to be able to uncheck Windows 8 and Windows Phone 8.1 from the list of Targets. However, I'm unable to do so.

When I right click on the project and choose properties I see this:
[Project Properties showing Windows 8 and Windows Phone 8.1 as targets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zscNi.jpg)

When I click the "Change..." button I only see these options:
[Change Targets options that don't include Windows 8, or Windows Phone 8.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtKqX.jpg)

The "Install Additional Targets" link just takes me here: (Not helpful)
https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/visual-studio-sdks

Any idea how I  can remove these targets and start making use of my WCF web services?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You no longer pick targets in a .NETStandard project.  There is a walk-through [located here](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/blob/master/docs/core/additional-tools/wcf-web-service-reference-guide.md), it recommends opening a github issue if you have trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your comment Hans.

For anyone else running into the same problem with adding a Service Reference I followed these steps, which don't make *any* sense, but they worked:

1. Right click on the Xamarin project and choose Manage NuGet Packages. Uninstall Xamarin Forms.
2. Close and re-open Visual Studio.
3. Right click on the Xamarin project and choose Properties. Click the "Change..." button under Targeting. The .NET Framework dropdown was automatically set to 4.5 for me. I changed it to 4.6. Click OK. (Mine still said 4.5 on the properties window, but that's OK)
4. Close and re-open VS.
5. Go back to Manage NuGet Packages and reinstall Xamarin Forms.
6. Close and re-open VS.
7. Viola. Magic. I can now add Service References.